# My menu bar dissapeared with autooptimize

Tags: menus, themes, custom-header

After setting up auto optimize my menu bar is gone. You can still click the buttons where they would be but it is invisible.

Please help. This is a production website I can't have it like this for long.

Comment: give me the link so I can check it

Comment: https://bit.ly/2NXISs6 (it is a shortened link so this question doesn't get indexed)

Comment: You should raise this with the Autoptimise support, 3rd party plugins are not in scope here and are off topic. Until then have you considered disabling the plugin until a solution is found?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what is the reason without seeing the site before autoptimize and withour looking at it's code, but...

First of all - you have many JS errors on your site. It can suggest that either your site is poorly coded or that autoptimize has done something bad.

The second option wouldn't be a surprise for me - this plugin is rather bad idea and most of the time it doesn't do anything good. Very often it causes JS conflicts, and even worse - it kills the performance (site gets slower than without autoptimize).

My recommendation? Delete autoptimize and remove all the mess done by this plugin. And if site really needs optimization after that - do it properly and don't believe in fairytales that some plugin will do everything automatically...